# How best to paint over melamine facing to look like painted wood?

Tags: paint, cabinets

I know you're not supposed to ask for product recommendations on here, but how would you recommend painting over melamine faced chipboard so it looks like other woodwork?

I need to match actual painted wood in a specific colour with an eggshell finish, so I'm thinking of some kind of surface primer that I can paint over as if it were wood. I've seen expensive spray primers designed for metal and plastics, and also "cabinet and wardrobe paint" by the tin which is considerably cheaper.

What's the best approach?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "look like pained wood" ?  Do you want it to have an underlying wood grain?  Or you really just want to paint it and get a smooth, durable finish like wood?  Are you concerned with painting the melamine or the chipboard base and end-grain?

Comment: No grain showing. Smooth like a skirting board. Just noting that the top coat will be eggshell, as opposed to matching a wall painted with emulsion. Concern is mainly adhesion.

Comment: "Which primer is best" or "Where do I find this primer" are shopping questions.  This sounds like a good "how do I do this" question.  It might be a duplicate question, but I don't think it falls into "shopping or recommendation".

Comment: You need to sand the melamine to remove the sheen, you want it to be dull otherwise nothing will stick to it very well.